# How to place an app icon like in windows in Mac application?

Tags: macos

Could anyone help me out as,how to place an app icon in title bar in Mac application.I want to place the app icon in top-left corner in title-bar like in windows application.Do we have any constrains in doing so...?

Comment: That would totally contradict the design of app in OSX. So why do you want to do this.

Comment: Actually i am working on,to  port a window application to Mac,its the customer requirement to put their brand logo as app icon,but how could achieve this in Mac platform.

Comment: Well you don't, unless you are writing you own window chrome. The place where the icon is in windows is where the close, minimize and full screen button are on windows. So you should tell your customer that OSX is not windows and that things will not be an exact copy and change will be made to match the UI for OSX. If you really must you will write you own window chrom which will mean that you app is hard to maintain as different version of OSX will behave differently.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for mi query,could u please suggest a sample app to refer the standard GUI of Mac ,Hope no storyboard support for Mac applications.

Comment: Asking for sample app/code or any offsite resource is offtopic. You could just read the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html) which will tell you how a OS X app should be designed.